# Best way to create content type and taxonomy on Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-taxonomy, contenttype

I'm going to try to explain my project.

I have one section to create on my drupal's site called "Press Room" in this section the users access it via menu item called "Shows". The mainly idea is that the second level of this menu will be created with taxonomy vocabulary called shows and the terms of this are for example:

-Shows(Voclabulary)
-Heartland(term)
-Bulloch Family(term)

And now the next step is create for each one of the terms the next structure:
-About
-Press Materials
-Video
-Fotos

To be more specific I've attach two piece of wireframes of these.

What is the best way to do that?
Thanks!!

[The menu show like that][1]
![The content once you click in the menu][2]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tijAU.png
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oifQ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can propose a solution although there are too many options here.

1) Heartland(term) -Bulloch Family(term): there is no need to use taxonomy terms, they can be node types (let's call it "Show" content type).

2) About, Press Materials, Video, Photos and Contact will be 5 node types too. But these will have a [reference field](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) to the node types above (Shows).

3) The display page of each Show will be a [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) that will display the node Show and the content that are referencing this node.

4) Menu can be created by hand (if shows are not too many) or by a views that will show a list of node links.

Examples:

- http://ericgilbertsen.com/2013/06/create-related-content-blocks-drupal-7-views-entity-reference
- http://www.webomelette.com/related-content-block-views-drupal-7

Comment: Perfect, it works amazing, I got so confused for the multiple solutions about this, but in particular your solution appears solve my problem, thanks a lot